# Deep-Linking within Android WebView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-webview

I'm trying to redirect my app to a new activity referenced via deep link on a webpage viewed with WebView.

I have an override which I'm creating my WebViewClient with.

```
class myClient : WebViewClient(){
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
        if (url.toString().startsWith(DEEP_LINK_PREFIX)) {
            var intent: Intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url))
            if (intent != null) {
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "no_apps_to_handle_intent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return true
        }

        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url)

    }
}
```

However, when I try to build I'm getting the following error:

```
e: /home/mpoletiek/AndroidStudioProjects/TestApp/app/src/main/java/com/example/testapp/MainActivity.kt: (45, 31): Type mismatch: inferred type is Intent but Context was expected
```

All the examples I can find on the web use Intent and startActivity this way, what am I missing?

Thanks,

Comment: So I got it to compile by calling startActivity() as a property of the activity class I wanted to start.

```var profile: ProfileActivity = ProfileActivity()

            var intent: Intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url))

           if(intent != null){
                profile.application.startActivity(intent)
            }```

However, now everytime it's triggered, Java complains that intent is null.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by passing the MainActivity's context to my custom WebViewClient class.

```
class myClient(context: Context) : WebViewClient(){
    var myContext = context
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {


        if (url.toString().startsWith(DEEP_LINK_PREFIX)) {
            var intent: Intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            Log.i(INFO_TAG,"INTENT TRIGGERED: "+url.toString())

            myContext.startActivity(intent)

            return true
        }

        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url)

    }
}
```